# cassandra with Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, spring-data

I'm trying to connect to cassandra database using spring data (preferably jpa). I can not find any clera example how to do it, no guide. I found some for MongoDB and Neo4j, but none for cassandra. On mail page of spring there is a mention of coassandra project but none exmaple or guide is provided. Can any one help?

Comment: This should be the starting point :   This has sufficient example to work on repositories :                                                                  http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of spring-data-cassandra are you using?

- v.1 https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra v.
- v.2 https://github.com/SpringData/spring-data-cassandra

For v.1 see http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/1.1.0.RC1/reference/html/#cassandra-connectors

I'm using v.2 and also had problems with finding tutorials/examples. But there are test inside the lib itself. See eg. spring-data-cassandra/cassandra/src/test/resources/org/springdata/cassandra/test/integration/config/XmlConfigTest-context.xml - you need to change only few things to make it work with your DB. When cofig is ready you can use CqlOperations to run your queries:

```
@Autowired
private CqlOperations cassandraTemplate;

cassandraTemplate.buildSaveNewOperation(new Foo("bar")).execute();
```

And that's basically it :)

Comment: sory but this project seems unclear for me. I have found XmlComfigTest-context.xml file but I have no ide what to change. Also after opening project in NetBeans, both subproject "Spring Data Cql" and "Spring Data Cassandra" are not loaded properly - both have "!" makrs. And also I don't see where is main porject with opening database and basic operations. 
Could you expalin it for me or create simple project that just connect to simple db and perform some CRUD operations?

Comment: @Kula, you do realise that we are NOT talking about a project which is USING spring-data-cassandra, right? We're talking about spring-data-cassandra _itself_. What I suggested is to use their tests (which they developed to verify their lib is working fine). If you have ever created tests for your project I hope you are able to use their test as an example for your app :)

So, you DO NOT have a 1 main project. Because there are 2 subprojects - "Spring Data Cql" (which is basic one) and "Spring Data Cassandra" (which extends what CQL project is offering).

Comment: As to XmlComfigTest-context.xml file - you have to change it so that is connects to YOUR database :) So you need to substitute valid values for ${cassandra.contactPoints} , ${cassandra.port} and ${cassandra.keyspace} (or to set it in a properties file defined by <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/org/springdata/cassandra/test/integration/config/cassandra.properties" />).
Then you can also tune your connection by playing with other params (you know, like pooling options) but for a start you just have to configure the connection.

Comment: Ow, you should also comment out "<cassandra:table" entries as it should refer to your classes (that you will create in the future). I also had to comment out "compression="SNAPPY"" since this setting requires snappy lib (which is a compression/decompression library; not necessary for test/dev stage of the project :)).

Comment: "after opening project in NetBeans, both subproject [...] are not loaded properly - both have "!" makrs" - those are maven projects. I don'n know NetBeans but you have to create it and build it as a maven project. So that all necessary libs are imported etc.

Comment: Ok, Some elements just not build correctly. I have further questions. I found test in CassandraTemplateTest.java. I would like to add to method findOneTest() my test for connection. I have cassandra with keyspace matching configuration from CassandraTestConstants.java, I have created my own class in or.springdata.cassandra.test.integration.table but it doesn't work at all. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

I used spring-data-cassandra-1.1.2.RELEASE. Here are 2 links which provide you detailed steps to configure Cassandra with Spring Data: [link1](http://www.opencredo.com/2014/10/23/spring-data-cassandra-overview/) and [link2](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/1.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/cassandra.core.html).

I followed the XML configuration way mentioned in link2, but faced one problem. I guess the ticket for this problem is [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-129) and is still open. This problem was resolved by just removing the id attribute from `<cassandra:template id="cassandraTemplate" />`. This code is from the config xml shown in the section 4.3.2 of link2.

Apart from this I did not face any problems and the Spring data Cassandra integration worked fine.

Section 5.1 from [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#cassandra-getting-started) link can also be used.